# What is row-level isolation?

Tags: database, database-design, cassandra

Say, I want to update the rows where `age = 20`, I start 2 concurrent updates, in the first one I change `20` to `21` in the second one I change `20` to `22`.

With row level isolation,

- Will the entire set of rows where `age = 20` be isolated, meaning that at the end of my update that entire set of rows will have `22` or `21` for `age` everywhere?
- Or is it only the current row that we are writing to, that will be isolated, meaning that at the end of my update that set of rows will have `22` in some places and `21` in the others?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying `age` column existing in multiple partitions or rows and you want to update them all at once? You can achieve atomicity and isolation when targeting a single partition, but only atomicity when targeting multiple partitions.

Note that Cassandra is not an ACID database and does not have transactions, although you can achieve linearizable consistency with paxos (lightweight transactions).

Comment: Say, I have `age  = 20` in row 1 and row 5. I update the table with one transaction doing `update table t set age = 21 where age = 20` and another with `update table t set age = 22 where age = 20`, after these 2 complete is it possible to have 22 in row 1 and 21 in row 5?

Comment: The example update your talking about is impossible to make in Cassandra so I guess no its not possible? :) Really I think part of the misunderstanding here is that there are _no transactions_. You can update multiple rows within a partition in a batch and have them applied atomically in isolation. If you just issue a series of updates that update all rows that have age=22 (which is non-trivial and basically shouldnt be done - the data model is wrong) they will not occur in isolation.